# Uncaught Typeerror: cannot set properties of undefined (setting '1')

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently making an incremental game and I am making achievements. When the earn function tries to set the value   of the awarded list in the achievement object from false to true, I get this error:

Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '1')

The awarded list is clearly defined as I mentioned before, so why does it say undefined?

An addon error is when I click the object that gives score, the score stays at 0, and there is no error when I click.

here is code if it helps:

```
awarded: [false, false],
    earn: function(index) {
        this.awarded[index] = true; //the error comes from this line
        display.updateAchievements();
    }
```

please tell me if you need to see any more code.

Comment: I need more context, your type definition

Comment: @tomoe what do you mean by type definition?

Comment: yep, and your code is a object ?

Comment: yes, it is an object. Do you need to see the entire object?

Comment: I try it, but it works        ```const op = {
  awarded: [false, false],
  earn(index: number) {
    this.awarded[index] = true
    display.updateAchievements();
  },```
}

Comment: Depending on how you are calling `earn`, `this` may mean different things. I think, What @tomoe meant is provide how you declared your object and how you are using it.

Comment: yes @Orifjon it's right

Comment: I am using { this } as referring to the whole object.

Comment: well, here is a link,  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDDGHsDsGcBcAIAmBLaAHANgQwJ7wLzwDew8Z8ArmolrAKYCCoAFsnQG50C2dks0ACgCUxAL7BxICDATg0BYqXhYA7lgBOiOogBc8ANoAzLBmh0ANPGOm6AXXNK6GyAOSQtADz2QKXAEZ06iIk5PCwrNAAdKoaWoj6bp62CrDqFHRKZCjo2DiRVDT0TKwc3Lz8wgDcSqIOkgD09fDICCrg6gDW0ACEwHKRTuouAIxCQA

Comment: You try to delete the arrow function